# How to measure (or calculate) the interval between two js-function?

Tags: function, settimeout

My friend asked me a special javascript question yesterday, and i found i could not solve it because nobody will write code like this:

```
function fun(){
  fun1();
}
function fun1(){
  setTimeout(fun(), 10000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  fun();
});
```

And his question was: Could you tell me that how many seconds between first time execute fun1 and second time execute fun1? 10 seconds?
I don't think his code will execute in correct, and i test his code via chrome dev-tools for inspecting that i am right.Chrome dev-tools print a message:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I also wanna know how many seconds between first time execute fun1 and second time execute fun1 even though i'll never write code like that. Is there anybody know the answer about this question?

Comment: I think fun1 started execution after 10,9,8,7.....0....-n, because each time fun1 executed it will added/multiple one more instance in the memory. Critical to understand but interesting.

Comment: @SudipPal Thank you for your responding. I had found the key to solve his(my friend) problem. It will never wait for 10 seconds to execute fun, in the other words, it seem that no time interval between executing fun1 every two times. Fun1 will call fun() immediately when it call setTimeout(), but do not wait for 10 seconds.If you want ,you can write the code like the follow: setTimeout("fun()", 10000)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way:

```
var tm = null;
var times = 0;

function fun()
{
    var d = new Date();
    times++;
    if (times == 2)
        alert((d.getTime() - tm) + " milliseconds");
    else
    {
        tm = d.getTime();
        setTimeout(function () { fun(); }, 10000);
    }
}

fun();
```

Basically you're storing last time value and calculating the time difference the second time the function is called.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uwc6t/1/)